# Table alter script failing because it can't see what it's trying to add

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, ddl

I need to execute a script that adds a new column to a table, and then updated that column based on an existing column.

```
PRINT 'Adding Column to Table...'

ALTER TABLE dbo.Table
ADD [Column] DATETIME2 NULL;

PRINT 'Updating data...'
UPDATE dbo.Table
SET [column] = ISNULL([ModifiedDate],[CreatedDate]) 

PRINT 'Finalising table structure...'
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table
ALTER COLUMN [Column] DATETIME2 NOT NULL

PRINT 'Complete!'
```

However, when I execute it in one go, it errors on the Update, saying that 'Column' doesn't exist.

If I run it one line at a time, it works.

Is there a way to get around this?

I can bypass this by using an EXEC to do the UPDATE, but that seems hacky. is it the only option?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when the `UPDATE` is compiled, the column is not know.  I think you can fix that problem by inserting `GO` between the different commands.

But, why not just use a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table ADD [Column] AS COALESCE([ModifiedDate],[CreatedDate]) ;
```

With a computed column, you don't need to do an update, and the value is always correct.

Comment: That would have good a good idea. Issue is that the change is due to a bug. ModifiedDate and CreatedDate are audit fields and not meant to be used by the application, so we need a separate 'business value' column.

Answer (score 0):

I also think so as @Gordon said, you can get rid of the issue by using GO between the statements, as below:

```
PRINT 'Adding Column to Table...'

ALTER TABLE dbo.[Table] ADD [Column] DATETIME2 NULL;

GO

PRINT 'Updating data...'
UPDATE dbo.[Table]
SET [column] = ISNULL([ModifiedDate],[CreatedDate]) 

GO

PRINT 'Finalising table structure...'
ALTER TABLE dbo.[Table]
ALTER COLUMN [Column] DATETIME2 NOT NULL

PRINT 'Complete!'
```

Can you please try with this code. I have enclosed table name in square brackets, it's a reserved keyword so unable to execute in SQL2012 and it was working to my end without GO.